# D3 - Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I do not know why but I always got Uncaught TypeError at the linear() row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>D3 Sandbox - Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script>
        var chartData = [250,300,230,500,440,120,310,600];
        var width = 500;
        var height = 500;
        var barWidth = 40;
        var barOffset = 5;

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(chartData)])
            .range([0, height]);

        console.log(y(500));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to give them a fix value, but also not helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using d3 version 4.

So instead of this

```
d3.scale.linear()
```

use this

```
d3.scaleLinear()
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wvr01C05YBsvFF50r3S?p=preview)

API reference [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLinear)